# How to compress a GIF in Imagick PHP API

Tags: php, imagemagick, gif, imagick, image-compression

I am having to use the imagemagick PHP API, imagick, and find that my attempts to compress a GIF image are having no effect.

Here are the commands I am using:

```
    $_image = new Imagick( $image_url );
    $_image->setImageFormat( $type ); // can be GIF or JPEG     
    $_image->setImageCompressionQuality( $level ); // Any of 20, 40, 60, 80, 100
```

I get good results when using a jpeg, but nothing whatsoever when converting to a GIF and then trying to compress. Could it be something to do with the conversion?

Maybe I have to use a certain compression type for GIF's? eg:

```
    $_image->setImageCompression( imagick::COMPRESSION_...?? );
```

If anyone has any clues, then please help me out, as the documentation for this API is woeful.

Thanks!

Comment: GIFs don't support compression in order to reduce quality in the way JPEG files do - they use LZW lossless compression or nothing. In general, GIFs can only compress large areas of constant colour well - such as Computer Generated Graphics - but not life-like photos.

Comment: Ok, thanks Mark - it seems that a general misunderstanding on my part is the fault here. I'll go and read up.